# Rebinding DataGridViews' DataSource makes hidden columns visible

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

When I do

```
BindingSource mySource= (BindingSource)gridview.mySource;
gridview.DataSource=null;
gridview.DataSource=mySource;
```

it results in columns being hidden (`visible=false`) before now showing up in the datagridview.

Ultimately I just want to delete a row from the gridview, but I figured that removing it from the gridview won't work because of the datasource binding.

Comment: is the property AutoGenerateColumns of the datagridview set to false ?

Comment: Why don't you remove it from the **data source** then? Also, if you really want to rebind the way explained, set `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false` before doing  that.

Comment: Do you mean why I don't just modify the dataSource property of the grid view? If so I can't since I have to rebind an old version of it at some point. Problem with setting `AutoGenerateColumns` to true is that then other parts of the application (not written by myself, application is quite large) would break because they depend on columns being created in order to hide them then.

Comment: As mentioned, you should just delete the row from the source.  You didn't document the BindingSource class you are using.